# Drupal module for download limit

Tags: 7, files

Is there any Drupal 7 module there, that can restrict any user, based on role/privilege, number of downloads per day. For example, 'x' type of user can download 10 files/day.

Comment: I haven't seen a module that does that (doesn't mean there isn't one of course). If writing your own is an option, it wouldn't be that much work. [`hook_file_download()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7) is the key,  check out [Commerce File](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_file) as a starting point for the code, it has everything you need

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such module exist. But you can write your own module.  [Download Count](https://drupal.org/project/download_count) may help you while writing your custom module.